# What are the dimensions of this pomerium marker?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, roman-empire, archaeology, epigraphy

The [pomerium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomerium) of Vespasian from 75AD (pictured below) was moved to Santa Cecilia in Trastevere, Rome in the 20th century. What are its dimensions, and what is its height, measuring from street level to the top of the top slab which begins with the etching "IMP CAESAR"?

[image: Pomerium of Vespasian]

I found a translation for the text [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/edk7/5844752565):

> Imperator Caesar Vespasian Augustus, Pontifex Maximus, holding tribunician power for the sixth time, acclaimed imperator 14 times, father of his country, censor, consul six times, consul designate for a seventh, [and] Titus Caesar Vespasianus, son of Augustus, acclaimed imperator six times, pontifex, holding tribunician power for the fourth time, censor, consul four times, consul designate for the fifth, after the borders of the Roman people had been increased, enlarged and marked off the pomerium [by an additional] ?? feet.

I've searched many websites and can't find this information. Here are some of the webpages I've looked at:

- [The City of Walls](http://roma.andreapollett.com/S4/walls.htm),
- [Il pomerio che non ti aspetti](http://marcogradozzi.blogspot.com/2013/11/il-pomerio-che-non-ti-aspetti.html) ,
- [Chi era Costui - Scheda di Pomerio](http://www.chieracostui.com/costui/docs/search/schedaoltre.asp?ID=11673),
- <del>http://roma.andreapollett.com/S4/mura.html</del> (dead link),
- [BASILICA OF St. CECILIA IN TRASTEVERE](http://romapedia.blogspot.com/2013/09/basilica-of-st-cecilia-in-trastevere.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not "the" or "a" pomerium, merely a stone marking it ([Material: stone — cippus, part of pomerium](https://www.trismegistos.org/text/272597)) and it is found at [Epigraphische Text-Datenbank: Detailansicht](https://edh-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/edh/inschrift/HD028285)

> Transkription:    [Imp(erator) Cae]sar / [Vespasi]anus / Aug(ustus) pont(ifex) max(imus) / trib(unicia) pot(estate) VI imp(erator) XIV p(ater) p(atriae) / censor co(n)s(ul) VI desig(natus) VII / T(itus) Caesar Aug(usti) f(ilius) / Vespasianus imp(erator) VI / pont(ifex) trib(unicia) pot(estate) IV censor / co(n)s(ul) IV desig(natus) V / auctis p(opuli) R(omani) finibus / [pomerium ampliaverunt] / [terminaveruntq(ue)] // p(edes) [---]
>
> Majuskeln:    [ ]SAR  [ ]ANVS  AVG PONT MAX  TRIB POT VI IMP XIV P P
> CENSOR COS VI DESIG VII  T CAESAR AVG F  VESPASIANVS IMP VI  PONT TRIB
> POT IV CENSOR  COS IV DESIG V  AVCTIS P R FINIBVS  [ ]  [ ]
>
> P [ ]
>
> Literatur Hilfe:   AE 1900, 0102.
> AE 1901, p. 22 s. n. 77.
> AE 1901, p. 44 s. n. 157.
> CIL 06, 31538c.
> AE 1900, p. 35 s. n. 105.

And the [Epigraphic Database Roma](http://www.edr-edr.it/default/index.php) gives you the following measurements:

> Search for:
>
> [Record Number: EDR103989](http://www.edr-edr.it/edr_programmi/res_complex_comune.php?do=book&id_nr=EDR103989&fo_antik=&fo_modern=&fundstelle%5B%5D=&boolfundstelle=AND&fundstelle%5B%5D=&aufbewahrung%5B%5D=&boolaufbewahrung=AND&aufbewahrung%5B%5D=&denkmaltyp=&booldenkmaltyp=OR&denkmaltyp2=&ope_mis_alto=%3C%3D&mis_alto=&ope_mis_largo=%3C%3D&mis_largo=&ope_mis_spesso=%3C%3D&mis_spesso=&boollivelloSocialeTot=OR&Bibliografia%5B%5D=&boolBibliografia=AND&Bibliografia%5B%5D=&Testo=&boolTesto=AND&Testo2=&Apparato%5B%5D=&boolApparato=AND&Apparato%5B%5D=&dat_tag=&dat_monat=&ope_dat_jahr_a=%3D&dat_jahr_a=&ope_dat_jahr_e=%3D&dat_jahr_e=&periodizzazione=&bool=AND&ordinamento=id_nr&javasi=javascriptsi&se_foto=tutte&lang=en)
>
> 1 epigrafi su 87679 record totali 1 inscriptions found
>
> Record Number: EDR103989       TM Number: 272597   Ancient Region: Roma
> Current Region: I  Ancient City: Roma   TMGEO  Modern City: Roma
> Discovery Location: Roma, Trastevere, S. Cecilia, sotto la basilica
> Current Location: Roma, S. Cecilia in Trastevere   Object Type: cippus,
> pomerium   Material: lapis
>
> **Measuraments: Height: 65  –– Length: 62**
> **Width./Diam.: 10  –– litt. alt.: 3,2-6,5**
>
> State of textual preservation:
> tit. integer   Writing Technique: scalpro  Language: latina
> Inscription type: term. non sep.   Type of persons mentioned: imp.
> Bibliography: CIL 06, 31538c (1) cfr. pp. 3795 (2), 4359 (3) HD028285
> (A. Scheithauer) (4)

This is from an Italian website that takes some liberties when switching to English language. But the measurements are the same on both – and metric.
The abbreviation *litt.* stands for *litterae* (letters) and *alt.* for *alterum* (the others).

(List of standard abbreviations: [PDF](http://udallasclassics.org/wp-content/uploads/maurer_files/APPARATUSABBREVIATIONS.pdf))

Comment: Very nice work. The 65 and 62 seem to be centimeters. Can someone familiar with this database explain "10 litt. alt.: 3,2-6,5"? Ten lines of text between 3 and 6 centimeters tall?